# How to set method onItemClick to open a Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm building an app, and I run on a problem with Google Maps. I wrote most of the code, but I don't how how to set that when user clicks on item(method onItemClick), in my case I have ListView on Firebase that is showing Tours of concerts, which you can see here:[my tours listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SWij.png) to open a specific place and show it on map. For example, user clicks on Anaheim, CA concert and it shows where that place is. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {



private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 10;
private GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener mCustomOnMapClickListener;

private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private MapFragment mMapFragment;
@BindView(R.id.lvTours) ListView lvTours;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    this.initialize();
}



public void initialize(){
    this.mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fGoogleMap);
    this.mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    this.mCustomOnMapClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            MarkerOptions newMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            newMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.tour));
            newMarkerOptions.title("Tour");
            newMarkerOptions.snippet("It' was here!");
            newMarkerOptions.position(latLng);
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(newMarkerOptions);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    UiSettings uiSettings = this.mGoogleMap.getUiSettings();
    uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    uiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    this.mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this.mCustomOnMapClickListener);
}




private boolean hasLocationPermission() {

    String LocationPermission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    int status = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, LocationPermission);
    if (status == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        this.mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        return true;

    }
    return false;
}

private void requestPermission() {
    String[] permission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapActivity.this, permission, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
}

@OnItemClick(R.id.lvTours)
public void onClick()
{


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your coordinates, you can build a `LatLng(latitude, longitude)` object 
then you can move the camera of your map like this:
build a new camera position using CameraPosition.Builder() and then ask to your mGoogleMap to animate to that position:

```
CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(location)
                .zoom(16f)
                .bearing(0.0f)
                .tilt(0.0f)
                .build();
mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position), null)
```

using that position you can even put a marker on the map:

```
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
            .title("some title"));
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you need further information on how the camera works I highly suggest you to take a moment and read the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views)

Comment: This was helpful, but one problem remains. I have a method onItemClick, which you see at the end of my code. Now, I want whenever I click on any of Tours item, that is, list of objects, to show me a map with that place. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: hum, I'ts since I use Kotlin that I don't use butterknife but, if I didn't recall it wrong, you can do like that: `@OnItemClick(R.id.listView)
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, int position) {
}`. having the position of your clicked element you'd be fine